# Change PHP Variable when an <a> tag is clicked

Tags: php, html

I have a simple PHP file (test.php):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        $requestedPage = "";
        if ($requestedPage){
            include_once("$requestedPage.php");
        }
        else{
            include_once("index.php");
        };
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

And an other PHP file (index.php):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        echo "<a>Index</a>";
        echo "<a>Infos</a>";
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

My goal is to load the test.php file and include index.php when a session starts.
When one of the *a* tags is clicked the *$requestedSite* variable should change accordingly and the page should reload with the .php file included.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Thank you for the info! I will make sure to update this question and create new ones which complies with your request.

Answer (score 2):

I really don't understand what are you going to do and your code does not look like what you want to do.

Here is the fault I found your code:

1. The link will no do anything because you just Index there is no location to go.
2. $requestedPage = "" look you initialized with null so if you link properly it will go always index.php

So I wrote a code for you and hope it will work for you:

**Index.php**

```
    <html>
     <head>
     </head>
      <body>
       <?php
        echo "<a href='test.php?name='>Index</a>";
        echo "<a href='test.php?name=info'>Infos</a>";
       ?>

      </body>
     <html>
```

**test.php**

```
<html>
 <head>
  </head>
    <body>
    <?php
       // $requestedPage = $_GET["name"];
        $requestedPage = $_REQUEST["name"];
       if ($requestedPage=='info'){
          include_once("info.php");
        }
        else if($requestedPage=='other') {
            include_once("other.php");
        }
        else{
        include_once("index.php");
       }
     ?>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Now if you want to get the full URL of the current URL, here is the code:

```
echo $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

I think this might help you!!

Comment: In test.php you need to read name: $requestedPage = $_REQUEST["name"];